# Show that normal random variable $X \notin L^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need to show that if $X$ is normally distributed $N(m, \sigma^2)$ random variable it's true that$X \notin L^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. In other words:  $\exists C > 0: |X| \leq C$,$\mathbb{P}-a.e.$

I know the density formula for normal random variable but don't know how it'll help.

Comment: don't think this is true, consider the tails of the distribution $|X| >C$, this happens with non-zero probability.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst, yeah, I messed up, meant $ X \notin L^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please edit your post.

Comment: @NateEldredge, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $X \notin L^\infty$, you have to show that for every $C$, you have $P(|X| > C) > 0$.  Now think about how to express this probability as an integral involving the density.